# Typing in Web Browser (Firefox and Chrome) Text Boxes and Text Areas on Android is Awkward

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android, user-interface, text-input

There are several sites which have web browser text areas which you can type stuff in. When these sites are visited with Firefox or Chrome, and you want to enter more than 3 lines of text (for instance your text may end up wrapping up and spanning 5, 6, 7, or 8 lines), then it becomes awkward to move to the lines in the middle, since the android placeholders that can be used to select text will scroll up or down too fast to select the middle lines.

I would like to know whether there is a workaround for this (personally I would suggest that the text box / text area on such browsers running on Android devices be resizable by dragging the lower-right-hand-side corner of such text area box. Not sure if this is possible at the moment.

The best solution I've found for this so far is to try and download the corresponding apps for the websites you need to visit and enter this kind of text in, but this is a non-solution given that some websites will not have corresponding Android apps to be used to enter the given information more conveniently.

Anyone know whether Firefox and Chrome plan to support the feature I just mentioned?

Comment: Asking whether they plan to support the feature is kind of playing with crystal-ball, since until there's an official announcement by them, we don't have any clue and can only speculate (and thus, off-topic IMO). OTOH, some keyboards have built-in navigation: [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) (5-row only) and [Google Japanese Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.japanese) (maybe not so useful for most people).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to drag the placeholder, in a text area whose content is larger than the editing area, you can scroll the text by dragging on the editing area itself. This works in both Firefox and Chrome for Android.

Regarding to text area resizing, yes, this is possible. Resizable text area works in both Firefox and Chrome for Android ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oybv0zsz/2/)), but they must be enabled by the website with a CSS3 code.

If the website you frequents doesn't enable text area resizing, in Firefox Mobile you can use the [Stylish Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/stylish/?src=search) to force all text area to be resizable with a userstyle CSS like the following:

```
textarea { resize: both; }
```

Stylish add-on is fully supported in Firefox Mobile.

AFAICT, Chrome Mobile does not support Chrome extensions.